# VMware Fusion Windows 10 Guest can't connect to VPN

Tags: networking, macos, windows-10, vpn, vmware-fusion

I'm running a Windows 10 guest VM on an OS X host. The Windows VPN client is unable to connect to a VPN server. It says "Connecting to VPN" then "Verifying your sign-in info", then after spinning for around approx 30 seconds it comes back saying "Can't connect to VPN - A connection to the remote computer could not be established, so the port used for this connection was closed".

On looking at the event log it says:

> 20226 RasClient The user MYUSER dialed a connection named VPNNAME
>   which has terminated. The reason code returned on termination is 829.
>
> 20224 RasClient The link to the Remote Access Server has been
>   established by user MYUSER.
>
> 20223 RasClient The user MYUSER has successfully established a link to
>   the Remote Access Server using the following device:  Server
>   address/Phone Number = VPNIP Device = WAN Miniport (PPTP) Port =
>   VPN4-1 MediaType = VPN.
>
> 20222 RasClient The user MYUSER is trying to establish a link to the Remote
>   Access Server for the connection named VPNNAME using the following
>   device:  Server address/Phone Number = VPNIP Device = WAN Miniport
>   (PPTP) Port = VPN4-1 MediaType = VPN.

Note that I'm able to connect successfully to the VPN server using my OS X directly. Is there a reason my Windows 10 VM won't connect? Is this a known issue? I have the Windows Firewall switched off

Details:

```
Guest: Windows 10 Enterprise
Host: OS X 10.10.4
VMWare Fusion: 7.1.2
Network Adapter for VM: "Share with my Mac"
```